# Two or more runners for same repository in GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm using a repository in GitHub and using workflows to build and deploy my java code. I have successfully build my code and deployed it using the self-hosted runner server.

But my issue is, when I commit to `main` branch, it should be deployed to a runner running on **DEV** environment and when commmited to a branch named `release`, it should to be deployed to the runner server in **STG** environment. I'm not sure how to achieve that. Here is my workflow for the `main` branch:

```
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:

  build_push:
    name: Build and push image to ECR
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ap-south-1

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
        with:
          mask-password: 'true'

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ vars.ECR_REGISTRY }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ vars.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ vars.IMAGE_TAG }}
        run: |
          docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG

  deploy:
    name: Deploy on DEV server
    runs-on: self-hosted
    needs: build_push
    env:
      ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ vars.ECR_REGISTRY }}
      ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ vars.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
      IMAGE_TAG: ${{ vars.IMAGE_TAG }}
    steps:
      - name:  Retrieve authentication token
        run: aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-south-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ECR_REGISTRY
      - name: Pull the docker image
        run: docker pull $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
      - name: Delete old container
        run: docker rm -f test-insurance || true
      - name: Run the docker container
        run: docker run -d --name test-insurance $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
```

I am able to add more than one runner but does not know how to tell the workflow to use that runner machine. Upon googling, I only found solutions for using runner for different repositories under an organization. I would like to point the runner in the workflow so that different runner can be used to different branches under the same repositories.

Comment: As the operations seem to be the same for each environment, you could use a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) that would receive the `self-hosted runner` name as input. Then, you would have a main workflow that would trigger for commit to `main` and `release` branches, and that would call the reusable workflow according to the trigger, with the expected inputs.

Comment: I can create two workflows but can't trigger the other with the first two. Is there any other way so I can mention the servers in the workflow itself?

Comment: Could you explain the reason why it is not possible to trigger the reusable workflow from the other workflows?

Comment: I'm sorry but I think reusable workflow actually works for me. I thought it was another workflow where I needed to trigger using PAT. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: I actually tackled my problem before by changing `runs-on: [ self-hosted,stg ]` where I gave an extra tag to both DEV and STG env runners.

Comment: Great, I will add an official answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the operations seem to be the same for each environment, you could use a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) that would receive the `self-hosted runner` name as input.

Then, you would have a `main` workflow that would trigger for commit to main and release branches, and that would call the reusable workflow according to the trigger, with the expected inputs.

Example:

```
name: Reusable workflow

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      runner:
        description: The runner
        required: true
        type: string
      environment:
        description: The GitHub Actions environment
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, '${{ inputs.runner }}' ]
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    steps:
      [ ... ]
```

```
name: Deploy workflow

on:
  push:
    branches ['main', 'stg']

jobs:
  prod:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yaml
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    with:
      runner: "my-production-runner"
      environment: "PRD"

  stg:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yaml
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/stg'
    with:
      runner: "my-staging-runner"
      environment: "STG"
```